# Problem with Yocto recipe modification (.bbappend)

Tags: append, yocto, init, recipe

I am new in Yocto environment, and I am trying to modify my initscripts recipe (from Poky) with .bbappend file. The problem is that everything I tried with it, it never worked. My file (../sources/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_%.bbappend) contains:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "file://type.sh"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}/${sysconfdir}/init.d/test
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/type.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/test/type.sh
    update-rc.d -r ${D} type.sh start 30 2 3 4 5 .
}
```

It seems that nothing is working ("test" folder is not even created in the rootfs, nor with another folder in /etc).

If I write a mistaken file in SRC_URI in .bbbappend file, bitbake shows a warning (OK).

If I write some syntax error in .bbappend file, bitbake not finishes, it returns an error (OK).

Typing `bitbake-layers show-appends` , I can see that my .bbappend file appears and it is not skipped.

Maybe the problem is the bitbake, I am doing it with `bitbake core-image-minimal`, maybe I need another target.

Please, let me know any advice because I don't know what else I can check.

Thank you so much,

Comment: You mentioned your rootfs does not contain the init.d/ directory... but it is created by the original initscripts recipe already: are you sure your image contains initscripts at all?

Comment: you are right, I've just updated my explanation. I tried to simplify it... But it was too much; init.d folder is created with original initscripts recipe. Thank you for your answer, please let me know if you have any tip.